# Why isn't Split optimized?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following code. 's' is splitted twice to two different arrays.

```
string s = "1,2,3";
string[] arr = s.Split(',');
string[] arr2 = s.Split(',');

foreach (..)
{ // do something
}
```

When compiling this in release mode the IL looks like this, so Split is actually called twice. Is there a reason why this isnt optimized?

```
IL_0008: newarr [mscorlib]System.Char
IL_000d: stloc.s CS$0$0000
IL_000f: ldloc.s CS$0$0000
IL_0011: ldc.i4.0
IL_0012: ldc.i4.s 44
IL_0014: stelem.i2
IL_0015: ldloc.s CS$0$0000
IL_0017: callvirt instance string[] [mscorlib]System.String::Split(char[])
IL_001c: stloc.1
IL_001d: ldloc.0
IL_001e: ldc.i4.1
IL_001f: newarr [mscorlib]System.Char
IL_0024: stloc.s CS$0$0001
IL_0026: ldloc.s CS$0$0001
IL_0028: ldc.i4.0
IL_0029: ldc.i4.s 44
IL_002b: stelem.i2
IL_002c: ldloc.s CS$0$0001
IL_002e: callvirt instance string[] [mscorlib]System.String::Split(char[])
```

Comment: why don't you optimize the code yourself?

Comment: You are calling `Split` twice for 2 different arrays, so compiler calls `Split` twice. I don't understand your question. What kind of optimization that you are waiting for ?

Comment: Dear if you are calling Split twice for same string, then what is fault of compiler..

Comment: In between the two calls, the array could have changed (on a different thread)

Comment: The compiler has no information on whether `Split` is deterministic, nor whether it produces any side effects.

Comment: but the compiler *does* have that information. string is immutable and the argument and string is the same for both calls. So instead of doing the whole split logic it could create a copy of the first Array.

Comment: The compiler knows the same thing for Console.WriteLine. Should it optimize that as well?

Comment: The compiler *doesn't* have this information. An implementation of `Split()` may randomly permute the characters of the string and return each one as a separate string in an array - the function signature would be identical - so it may not be deterministic. And, as @adrianm points out, it may send the string to a `Console` or through `Tracing`, or to the file system, etc, so it doesn't know whether it has side effects.

Comment: still not convinced. Console.Write or Trace can be called from other threads so the compiler cannot make any assumptions for them. But in this example it is all local inside a function so no other thread can mess up things. And what do you mean with randomly permute a string? I thought string was immutable

Comment: The compiler has *no* specialized knowledge of the internal working of `Split` (nor any other function). `Split` could be doing anything, which (as we're trying to communicate to you) *may* mean that two successive calls produce *different* results, or that there are different, external, observable results. Just because *you* can read the documentation and have determined that `Split`, specifically, is unlikely to act in the manner, does *not* mean that the compiler has access to such knowledge.

Comment: I see. I was under the assumption that string and its functions was a special case to the compiler. So its not, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distilling comments down to an answer:

The compiler, in general, has no special knowledge on the contents of a method - even if it [*could*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) analyze the current implementation, it has no way to know whether that implementation would change in important details.

The two most obvious issues with the optimization you assume the compiler could perform are determinism and the presence of side effects.

1. Determinism - there's no guarantee that two successive calls to the same function will produce identical results, even in the absence of any (obvious) shared state.
2. Side effects - the function in question (or functions that it calls) could produce visible side effects - even as little as incrementing a call counter - such that calling it once or twice would have different overall effects.

Now, it is true that at times, the compiler can pull off tricks that we aren't able to ourselves - e.g. it *could* have knowledge that two successive calls to `Split()`, using a local reference that couldn't have been assigned a copy of a more visible reference, should produce the same result. But that's an *incredibly* specific optimization that's probably not worth the engineering effort.

In *general*, the compiler has no more knowledge than the method signatures. And, in the current incarnation of .NET, the method signatures provide no information on determinism and side effects.